# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler

Tags: java, apache, maven

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_extracting_ms_office_files.htm) and for some reason i get the following error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler

on line

> msofficeparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);

My POM file includes the following:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>         <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
>         <version>3.9</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>         <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
>         <version>3.9</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>         <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
>         <version>3.9</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
> <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
> <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
> <version>1.1</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
> <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
> <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
> <version>1.6</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

```
dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
<artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

so i really don't understand why this should happen.
Am i missing something i don't understand?

Thank.

**more investigations**

Well in a step by step debugging i actually get to the line where there exception is thrown. i can clearly see that the handler class and method are included in the library and i can go into them. but when the compiler tries, the exception is thrown.

Comment: Just guessing here, but I notice a lot of lower-case letters that, by Java conventions, should be upper-case. Check your capitalization in your class and method calls

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the latest version of jars. Sometimes some methods are removed or replaced.

Comment: wat? code is compiling fine. the expection is thrown inside the parser + the jars are latest versions i checked in maven repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your lib folder and check for multiple **poi-ooxml** jars with different versions.
If this is the case, remove the older jar, its probably coming from transitive dependency, so just exclude it in the pom.

Comment: To verify this i actually created a new maven project with only these dependencies and it still happens

Comment: It seems that in the end you were right. after removing poi-ooxml, the conflict was resolved. thanks